# I arrive on a white screen when I try to switch activities on my android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I just want to switch activity with a simple button

```
Button test = findViewById(R.id.please);

    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("MainActivity","I pass there ");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.d("MainActivity","I pass there too");
        }
    });
```

I don't have an error, I just arrive on a white screen and not on my new activity. Logs appear in my console. I also have a log when I create my second activity but this one doesn't appear.

for more code,
This is my manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ScheduleActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
              android:theme="@style/YourTheme">

    </activity>
</application>
```

TestActivity :

```
    public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Log.d("TestActivity","I arrived in Test Activity !!");
    }
}
```

the button in activity_main :

```
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="wtf"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/please"
    />
```

Activity_test :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello there! :D"/>
```

Comment: Post the code for TestActivity. I'm guessing you forgot to call setContentView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Overriding wrong onCreate method in TestActivity. You have to override this method:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
```

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: absolutely, this is my create in test  :  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Log.d("TestActivity","I arrived in Test Activity !!");

Comment: Basically when you are starting new activity you have to define it in the manifest.xml file and setContent view so the activity would have a view. Now I cannot tell what is the problem. So can you please share more code with us?

Comment: Yes indeed, I've done it. But unfortunately, the problem is not there :/ . In fact, my application run with no problem, I don't have an error message, just I d'ont arrive on TestActivity. I had more code if you're still okai to see. Thanks a lot for you time !

Comment: You are Overriding wrong onCreate method in TestActivity. You have to override this method: protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: So simple but I realy needed someone else to see this ! Thanks you so msh !! :D